# in GAE what is the reason to use something other then Key for Id?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, key, google-cloud-datastore

I started to develop an app in google app engine as my third year project. I have not had much practice with databases nor with JPA.

I was just wondering what is the reason to use something other then Key for Id.

Anyway it is going to be in the database, why not to use it?

We can declare an ID

```
@Id private Key id
```

or

```
@Id private long Id
```

etc.

But Key is gonna be assigned to any Entity in GAE anyway so why bother assigning something else as an ID?

There are other issues too, particularly with the relationships. For example if the Department has an Id which is Long, can the User (Department's child) also have an Id which is Long?

NO. Why?

The datastore has to store a reference of the parent-child relationship in the child. Hence it needs to have a field which is an Id in the child where it can store the Long value of the parent.

May be what I am asking is what are the traditional reasons of why someone would uses String, long, etc. And why you still want to have Id as long or string even in presence of key class

Comment: Unfortunately this question doesn't make much sense. Can you give an example of when you've seen this?

Comment: You should spend a bit more time with an App Engine documentation, where they explain entity keys and identifiers: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities. There are also a number of good tutorials that you can google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there is no usable Key.  Consider logs for example.  Logs often duplicate all fields including the date and time, and have no unique column.

Edit - The decision of what becomes the key depends on the data being stored.  If there is a unique field, use it.  If there is no unique field, let the Datastore generate one.

Consider a GAE based data logging application.  Clients may post records to be logged, including time to the nearest second and a client name.  AppEngine will accept multiple records from the same client, during the same second, but must still have a unique identifier per record.  That is what I meant by duplicate records in logs (I happen to be developing such a GAE project).  For example, a fault might log many identical error messages in quick succession.

Turning to your added questions, other applications can often provide a field that is unique per record, as stevep is also helpful to point out.  Using that unique field is almost always more convenient for your software and for end users to deal with than the unique identifiers that GAE can optionally generate.  Here the example is that you could design a GAE based site that refers to your StackOverflow account as Nomad or as user 3194545.  The name is more memorable than the generated Id number.  Don't worry about whether StackOverflow runs on GAE, it could but that isn't the point, this is an example.

About your next question, if Department has an Id that is long, a User (child of Department) can also have an Id that is long.  Even the same value, because the two identifiers are being used within different scopes.

Since you say you're new to this, study [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) thoroughly.  Do not confuse Id and Key.  You may specify an Id or let Datastore do that.  If you choose to specify the Id, you may use a String or a long integer.  Datastore creates every Key, and that is a much more complex piece of data.  The reason Google gives developers alternatives is because many developers want alternatives.  Whether you use JPA, JDO or the low-level Datastore API, the concepts are the same.

Comment: updated question, my question is directed to GAE datastore specifically, and I am not sure in your answer, sorry, may be could you expand it a bit please

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. But I am quite sure in my reasoning about a long ids, that is not the point anyway. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Key is now a long int that may cause you problems with Javascript. YMMV. This was an issue when GAE made the change a good few months back which is why you have the option of a shorter int key if you want it. Beyond this, there is very often IMHO the need to define a unique key based on something you can build with your client-side logic. Why not do this if you can? The more you can rely on client-side ids for get_by_key lookups the better you are. With GAE, one should always look to the client for a means to request an entity by key name rather than by querying the DB for ids. Again, all such design suggestions are all IMHO, so purists who insist on other approaches (such as always using the natively assigned ID value) are free to differ.